# Is there a better solution or is this fine the way I'm parsing the data to a DB?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm new to programming and Python. While studying python I am doing all the problem sets and exercises but also working on my own projects to help me learn.

Some of the things I need to do in my project we have not covered in detail so I have been doing extra research. While my code below works well, I am not sure if this is the correct way to implement it.

Basically, I am parsing a small XML file, less than 10KB in size. I loop through the file and only copy four fields and their values. I then insert those values into a temp sqlite DB for me to further manipulate and add more fields or change the data.

So I thought, instead of writing two separate functions, one to parse the XML file and then one to update the DB, I can use one small function to do both as the xml files are quite small and I am not worried about performance.

So, as one loop completes finding the data I need, I have my loop update the DB the same time.

Below is my current code I am using. But I don't want to use it if this is not the way to do it. Trying to not learn any bad habits if I can help it.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

def parseCT(self):
    """
    Read data from XML File.
    Parse XML data and insert data into Temp DB file
    """

    # Open XML file so we can access data
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file='acs.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Create temp DB to store read XML data
    con = sqlite3.connect('ct_temp.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE XMLTable (
                ID TEXT NOT NULL, Description TEXT,
                VariableType TEXT, Text TEXT,
                PRIMARY KEY (ID))''')
    con.commit() # update and save changes to our temp DB.

    txt1 = ''
    txt2 = ''
    txt3 = ''
    txt4 = ''

    # Loop to find the elements we are looking for
    for elem in tree.iter():
        if elem.tag == 'ID':
            txt1 = elem.text  
        elif elem.tag == 'Description':
            txt2 = elem.text
        elif elem.tag == 'VariableType':
            txt3 = elem.text
        elif elem.tag == 'Text':
            txt4 = elem.text

    cur.execute('INSERT INTO XMLTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                (txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it *work?* If this is working code that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the problem.

Comment: Hi. Yes it seems to be working. But Im not sure if what Im doing is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findtext`:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO XMLTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            (root.findtext('ID'), root.findtext('Description'),
             root.findtext('VariableType'), root.findtext('Text')))
```

Comment: Thanks, will go try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code works, in order to simplify the code, you may do:

```
# Initial list to maintain the order of params in `INSERT` statement
query_params_order = ['ID', 'Description', 'VariableType', 'Text']

# `.format` will replace `{}` in query based on the order of params in `list`
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE XMLTable (
            {} TEXT NOT NULL, {} TEXT,
            {} TEXT, {} TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))'''.format(*query_params_order))

con.commit()

# `dict` with tag and text mapping
params_dict = {elem.tag: elem.text for elem in tree.iter()}

order_params = [params_dict.get(param, '') for param in query_params_order]

cur.execute('INSERT INTO XMLTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            order_params)
```

instead of:

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE XMLTable (
            ID TEXT NOT NULL, Description TEXT,
            VariableType TEXT, Text TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID))''')
con.commit() # update and save changes to our temp DB.

txt1 = ''
txt2 = ''
txt3 = ''
txt4 = ''

# Loop to find the elements we are looking for
for elem in tree.iter():
    if elem.tag == 'ID':
        txt1 = elem.text  
    elif elem.tag == 'Description':
        txt2 = elem.text
    elif elem.tag == 'VariableType':
        txt3 = elem.text
    elif elem.tag == 'Text':
        txt4 = elem.text

cur.execute('INSERT INTO XMLTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
            (txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4))
```

It will behave same as your code but is more clean and scalable.

Comment: Thanks so much. Appreciate the help. Will practice this a few times.